# REFERENCE KEY in node-orm2

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-orm2

I am working on REST API based on node.js and i chose `postgresql` database to store data. Suppose that this database has two tables names `User` and `Comment`. Any `Comment` belongs to One `User` and when we decide to remove an `User`, the `Comment`'s of him/her must be removed.  So, I designed my table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    user_id SERIAL,
    username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT uq_user UNIQUE (username)
)

CREATE TABLE Comment(
    comment_id SERIAL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_cmnt PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cmnt FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(user_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

But i don't run this code and use [`node-orm2`](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) instead. I designed two simple models to handle this simple code:

```
var User = db.define('user', {
    username: {
        type: 'text',
        size: 32, // VARCHAR(32)
        required: true, // NOT NULL
        unique: true // UNIQUE INDEX
    },
    password: {
        type: 'text',
        size: 32, // VARCHAR(32)
        required: true // NOT NULL
    }
}, {
    id: 'user_id' //SERIAL
});

var Cmnt = db.define('comment', {
    content: {
        type: 'text',
        required: true // NOT NULL
    }
}, {
    id: 'comment_id' //SERIAL
});

Cmnt.hasOne('user', User, {required: true}); // CREATE ASSOCIATION KEY
```

and synchronize database with these models :

```
db.sync();
```

Now, I want to insert new comment belongs to user which user_id doesn't exist. So, the `Comment` model accepts this and insert the row into `comment` table.

My question is, how can i do some things like `REFERENCE KEY` and the `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use deferrable like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Comment(
    comment_id SERIAL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_cmnt PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cmnt FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(user_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
```